# Exception calling "GetList" with "1" argument

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am getting the following exception when I tried to GetList:

```
Exception calling "GetList" with "1" argument(s): "<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"
At C:\Scripts\teaCvProfileUpdate\uploadTeaCvsToSharepoint.ps1:37 char:36
+ $cvDocumentLibrary = $spWeb.GetList <<<< ("/people/User Resumes/Forms/")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

These are the relavent 3 lines of code (powershell):

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb("/")
$cvDocumentLibrary = $spWeb.GetList("/people/User Resumes/Forms/")
```

Can somebody tell me why this is happening?

Thanks. :)

Comment: The error isn't very helpful. What does this do for you? `Get-SPSite -Identity http://SPServer | Get-SPWeb` ?

Comment: Andy, that returns a list of URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I had to do to make it work:

```
$mySiteUrl = "https://snip.snip.snip/people"
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $mySiteUrl
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$cvDocumentLibrary = $spWeb.GetList("/people/User Resumes")
```

Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb("people")
$cvDocumentLibrary = $spWeb.GetList("/people/User Resumes")
```

Comment: Thank you Rich, for the suggestion but this produces the exact same error.

Comment: I would confirm that your URLs are correct. What is the value of $mySiteUrl? Is "people" a subsite under your root website? Does the User Resumes URL actually have a space in it?

Comment: Rich, I had to add '/people' to the $mySiteUrl variable and it worked when I used `.OpenWeb("User Resumes")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SPWeb.GetList() expects the Server Relative URL to a list.  So in your example, it would be:

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $mySite;
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb();
$myList = $spWeb.GetList($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/MyList");
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error message too. I discovered when I try to open a list from the parent/top level site using a relative URL, I encountered the error because of too many forward slashes returned. Example of the issue using Adam's code: If $mySite = "https://site.com", then ($spWeb.ServerRelativeURL + "/Lists/MyList") returns "//Lists/MyList". This isn't a valid relative URL. Remove the forward slash in front of Lists and the code below works for me.

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $mySite;
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb();
$myList = $spWeb.GetList($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "Lists/MyList");
```